# How to Configure SSO With Oracle Smartview Using Okta Or Pingfederate?

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, okta, pingfederate, smartview

Currently working on configuring SSO for Oracle Smartview client that accesses the Oracle EPM suite of BI Tools. Pingfederate SP and Okta Idp configured with multiple AD data sources is configured.

Would appreciate if anyone would share their experience in the approach and configuration steps taken to enable SSO for Smartview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google indicates that Smart View can consume a header for a user ID. This allows you to use any standard mechanism for header injection available in your IAM environment. You mentioned PingFederate as your SP. You didn't mention if Smartview is behind any proxy (like Nginx or Apache).

Ping has a number of integration mechanisms for header injection, ranging from the various integration kits in PingFederate (Java, Apache, IIS), as well as PingAccess which is the Ping Identity standard WAM tool.

With all of the options available to you for integration, providing you step by step guidance requires more information. I would suggest a call to your Ping account team.

Comment: I looked at this page at Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/OPUSC/supported_sso_methods.htm#OPUSC-hss_sso_105

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew. This clarified most of what we are looking for.